# xdt with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, xdt-transform

Actually i dont have much knowledge about xtd-transform.
What i need in my xdt file :

```
<add key="EndpointName" value="SomeValue" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
```

routine work that im doing in powershell :

```
$cache.SetAttribute("key","EndpointName")
$cache.SetAttribute("value","SomeValue")
$cache.SetAttribute("xdt:Transform","SetAttributes(value)")
$cache.SetAttribute("xdt:Locator","Match(key)")
```

And here are what i have. Dont match my points:

```
<add key="EndpointName" value="Email" Transform="SetAttributes(value)" Locator="Match(key)" />
```

So is it possible to create xdt:attribute using powershell scripts?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you try `$cache.SetAttribute("Transform", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform", "SettAttributes(value)")` it will probably create a random namespace prefix but it should not matter and if you really want xdt namespace prefix it should be doable once the above works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When XML namespaces are involved you need to use an XmlNamespaceManager e.g.:

```
$xdt = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform'
$xml = [xml]"<doc xmlns:xdt='$xdt'><add key='foo' value='foo' xdt:Transform='foo' xdt:Locator='foo'/></doc>"

$nsmgr = new-object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $xml.NameTable
$nsmgr.AddNamespace("xdt", $xdt)

$xml.doc.add.SetAttribute('Transform', $xdt, 'SetAttribute(value)') > $null
```

Results in:

```
<doc xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <add key="foo" value="foo" xdt:Transform="SetAttribute(value)" xdt:Locator="foo" />
</doc>
```